# Can I test vr games without a headset in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: virtual-reality, unreal-engine5

I need some way to test vr games without a headset because I do not have it at the moment, I just want to make a simple game that will be just on vr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes you can try**
[Using the Windows Mixed Reality simulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-mixed-reality-simulator)

> but it has few issues with Unreal Engine, But work perfect in other
> cases.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).